# Auto scale on azure app service command throwing ["UnsupportedMetric"] error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Following az-cli command not supporting metric for auto-scaling instances on azure app services.

```
# Create cpu autoscale rule
az monitor autoscale rule create --resource-group $COMMON_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME   \
  --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION_ID   \
  --resource $WEBAPP_NAME   \
  --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites'   \
  --autoscale-name "test"  \
  --condition "Percentage CPU > 75 avg 5m"  \
  --scale out 1
```

Response - Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.MonitoringServiceException' was thrown.. [Code: "UnsupportedMetric"]

I followed this Microsoft documentation -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/autoscale/rule?view=azure-cli-latest

I know, how to do auto-scale through azure portal but I want to do this using script.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to create an autoscaling policy and rules with the following steps.

***NOTE:** This is specific to Azure Service Plan but might work with other vmss.*

The Azure docs is specifically geared towards VMSS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/autoscale?view=azure-cli-latest so I had to manually create a Autoscale and rule, and view the JSON output to see the actual metrics name used.

```
RG="resource_group"
RESOURCE="service_plan_name"
```

First, create the Autoscale

```
az monitor autoscale create -g $RG --resource $RESOURCE \
--min-count 1 --max-count 4 --count 1 --email-administrator \
--resource-type Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
```

And then, create the scale Up/Down rule

```
az monitor autoscale rule create -g $RG --autoscale-name $RESOURCE \
--scale out 1 --condition "CpuPercentage > 80 avg 5m"

az monitor autoscale rule create -g $RG --autoscale-name $RESOURCE \
--scale in 1 --condition "CpuPercentage <= 40 avg 10m"
```

Answer (score 5):

I also tried with "Percentage CPU > 75 avg 5m" and got the same result "Unsupported Metric".
I tried creating the rule manually and looked at the JSON properties, the metric was mentioned as CpuPercentage.
So, with the following change in condition, it worked.

```
az monitor autoscale rule create \
--resource-group $resource \
--autoscale-name $autoscalename \
--scale out 1 \
--condition "CpuPercentage > 70 avg 5m"
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you create a rule based on how many request the web app gets and scales out its related service plan.

```
az monitor autoscale rule create  --resource-group MyResourceGroup   `
--resource MyWebSite  `
--resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites' `
--autoscale-name MyAutoScale    `
--condition "Requests >= 200 avg 5m"   `
--scale out 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response .. this works fine on no of requests..but how can we create rule-based on CPU/memory percentage?

Comment: any solution for rule-based on CPU/memory percentage?